# How to spawn a child_process with node.js and save the output to a file

Tags: node.js, bash, stream, child-process, spawn

I am trying to spawn a child process `/bin/bash` from my `Node.js` app and use use my app `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` for it, and at the same time I want to capture everything entered (stdin) and outputted (stdout) into a file called `inAndOut.log`.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var shell = spawn('/bin/bash', ['-l'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options Here there are examples. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: you've gotten any luck?

Answer (score 3):

Create a writable stream, and pipe the stdout to it:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("output-file");
const shell = spawn('/bin/bash', ['-l'], {});

shell.stdout.pipe(writeStream);
```